# Trying to use two scripts but only one of them works

Tags: animation, text

I'm trying to have two lines of headers with context change animation to work together like this:

```
<h4 class="slideshow__text-content" data-animate id='changetext'>Demo Auction Title</h4>
              <script>
                var text = ["Various Visual Placeholders", "Featuring: Artist Name #1", "Featuring: Artist Name #2",  "Featuring: Curator Name", "May 1 - June 1 2021"];
                  var counter = 0;
                  var elem = $("#changetext");
                  setInterval(change, 3000);
                  function change() {
                    elem.fadeOut(function(){
                      elem.html(text[counter]);
                      counter++;
                      if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 1; }
                      elem.fadeIn();
                    });
                  }
                </script>
              <h1 style="color: white"><div class="slideshow__text-content" data-animate id='auction-heading'>Demo Auction Title</h1>
                <script>
                  var text = ["Various Visual Placeholders", "Featuring: Artist Name #1", "Featuring: Artist Name #2",  "Featuring: Curator Name", "May 1 - June 1 2021"];
                  var counter = 0;
                  var elem = $("#auction-heading");
                  setInterval(change, 3000);
                  function change() {
                    elem.fadeOut(function(){
                      elem.html(text[counter]);
                      counter++;
                      if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
                      elem.fadeIn();
                    });
                  }
                </script>
```

Can someone please tell me why only one of them works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same variable and function names in both blocks, and they conflict because some of them are in the global scope. If you use non-overlapping names, that should fix it.

Here's the code for it. I may have changed a little more than I needed to, but it is a complete working example and it demonstrates the solution.

```html
<body style="background-color: gray">
<h4 class="slideshow__text-content" data-animate id='changetext'>Demo Auction Title</h4>
<h1 style="color: white"><div class="slideshow__text-content" data-animate id='auction-heading'>Demo Auction Title</h1>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  var text1 = ["Various Visual Placeholders", "Featuring: Artist Name #1", "Featuring: Artist Name #2",  "Featuring: Curator Name", "May 1 - June 1 2021"];
  var text2 = ["Various Visual Placeholders", "Featuring: Artist Name #1", "Featuring: Artist Name #2",  "Featuring: Curator Name", "May 1 - June 1 2021"];
  var counter1 = 0;
  var counter2 = 0;
  var elem1 = $("#changetext");
  var elem2 = $("#auction-heading");
  function change1() {
    elem1.fadeOut(function(){
      elem1.html(text1[counter1]);
      counter1++;
      if(counter1 >= text1.length) { counter1 = 0; }
      elem1.fadeIn();
    });
  }
  function change2() {
    elem2.fadeOut(function(){
      elem2.html(text2[counter2]);
      counter2++;
      if(counter2 >= text2.length) { counter2 = 0; }
      elem2.fadeIn();
    });
  }
  setInterval(change1, 3000);
  setInterval(change2, 3000);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Lionel! Could you please share with me an example of the solution as well? It will be super helpful as I'm very new to this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just added it! Please remember to click the checkmark afterwards if this solved your problem :)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, Lionel! Really appreciate it!